# sed comand to remove duplicate Records from file witout sorting

Tags: perl, shell, unix, awk, sed

source file

```
A B C
E F G
A B C
```

o/p Should  be

```
A B C
E F G
```

i dont want to use sort comand as it is adding blank line in the end.I used this

```
sed '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D'
```

but it required sorted data any alternative to sort the data instead of sed command..?

Comment: I guess this question has been answered here >10 times.

Answer (score 1):

awk is better suited for this by using an associative array with key as record itself:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' file

A B C
E F G
```

Comment: I Tried awk also but it is adding blank line in the end I am giving actual scenario   $ cat FoundationIssuerPlusDailyChange_ObjectRelType.txt_bkp
1'~'Issuer to Company'~'137'~'2#@#@#2'~'Contract to Underlying Security'~'21'~'21#@#@#wdm@wuvra96a0540:/opt/informatica/Informatica_Projects/wdm/infa_shared/SrcFiles
$ awk '!seen[$0]++' FoundationIssuerPlusDailyChange_ObjectRelType.txt_bkp
1'~'Issuer to Company'~'137'~'2#@#@#2'~'Contract to Underlying Security'~'21'~'21#@#@#
wdm@wuvra96a0540:/opt/informatica/Informatica_Projects/wdm/infa_shared/SrcFiles

Comment: That is only possible if input file has blank lines. In that case try: `awk 'NF && !seen[$0]++' file`